# MaxI, MinI, digits missing in android xml

Tags: android, android-layout

So while i try to build the AOSP Settings application i get this error

```
warn: removing resource com.android.settings:string/lineagelicense_title without required default value.
    warn: removing resource com.android.settings:string/lockscreen_visualizer_title without required default value.
    packages/apps/Settings/res/layout/preference_dialog_animation_scale.xml:38: error: attribute com.android.settings:digits not found.
    packages/apps/Settings/res/layout/preference_dialog_animation_scale.xml:38: error: attribute com.android.settings:maxI not found.
    packages/apps/Settings/res/layout/preference_dialog_animation_scale.xml:38: error: attribute com.android.settings:minI not found.
```

If I am right having the schema in the xml file should solve this issue, but its not working. 
Here is the XML Layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:settings="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="12dp">

        <!-- Static height enough to accommodate the text views in their biggest possible size,
        without having the dialog resize itself at any point. -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="64dp"
                 android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/scale"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.android.settings.IntervalSeekBar android:id="@+id/scale_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/container"
                settings:minI="0"
                settings:maxI="10"
                settings:defaultValue="1.0"
                settings:digits="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the solution to this myself. The minI, maxI and digits were defined in com.android.settings.IntervalSeekBar class. These actually are styleable attributes and needs to be declared in another attr.xml. 
Once I did that the error was solved.

Hopefully this will be helpful for someone who might face such issues in future.

Thanks.